# Cordova/Phonegap wake up app on incoming webrtc phone call

Tags: javascript, java, cordova, webrtc, phonegap

I have written an audio/video call hybrid app written with cordova/phonegap. I used

1) webrtc for actual streaming of audio or video

2) server sent events (SSE) to listen for incoming calls. https://apifriends.com/api-streaming/server-sent-events/

3) simple-peer https://github.com/feross/simple-peer

When the app is open, everything goes great, i can receive incoming call signals etc and connect. The problem is that when the app is off. I cannot open app or get any kind of indication of call status.

I decided to do some digging quickly found out that this was not possible from within a webview. I tried some plugins like https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode which worked great for some time but would quickly drain the battery and your app may be rejected on appstore notices.

When my app is opened, incoming calls will be correctly captured. all i need is to open the app. I read about background push messages (silent) but failed to get these to open app. The push messages handlers were only called when app is in foreground.

So i finally fell on this doc and its the closest i got with this answer. There is no direct support for background service in Phonegap/Cordova apps.

> The reason is that your hybrid app is written in JS, and your JS code
>   runs in an Activity that has a webview. As soon as you exit your app,
>   the app is suspended.
>
> If you really want to have background service in android, you can
>   write your Android service in Java (native) and call your service from
>   your JS code. (Native for background service & JS for your app)

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-run-cordova-plugin-in-android-background-service/6677/3

From the above, i gather i would have to do the actual logic of detecting incoming calls from the java service and if i detect anything i can force my application to open. Below is simple logic i do once app is open.

```
if (documentLoaded && isLoggedIn)
{
//url returns json only if there is an incoming call otherwise empty

var source = new EventSource("https://www.url.com/api/sse/incomingcall.php?userid=" + userid, {
        withCredentials: true
    });
source.addEventListener("incomingcalls", function (event) {
    var callSession = JSON.parse(event.data);
    // HandleIncomingCall();
}, false);
}
```

My issue is that i am not a java coder and havent written a plugin before. how would i create an android service that will listen to above url periodically and if detect any json open my app.

Comment: There's some background plugin for cordova, did you try one ?

Comment: yes i did, It worked BUT there was lots of warning of app rejection, It also would consume a lot of battery when i would disableWebviewOptimizations. to get it into what perfectly worked

Comment: oh ok, as you i m not good enough in Java, so i hope you ll find a solution. good luck